# Phonegap event for user returning to app again

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-3

How can I capture an event in Phonegap when the user changes to another app and get to my app again, is there an event for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap **RESUME** event

*This is an event that fires when a PhoneGap application is retrieved from the background.*

Please go through this link  [PHONEGAP RESUME](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#resume)